# how to reduce time to display a list (json object fetched from database) in a table using *ngFor structural directive?

Tags: angular5, angular6, angular-directive

I am fetching a json object using web API, and displaying it in a table using *ngFor Structural Directive. However the problem is, though the object gets fetched instantly and display in console, it takes time to display it in table. I want the object to be displayed in table instantly as soon as it comes into console.

component.html file;

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of orgData" id="{{data.Id}}">
          <td hidden><input type="number" id="1" value="{{ data.Id }}"></td>
          <td>{{ data.OrganisationName }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.ContactPerson }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.ContactPersonHPNo }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.ContactPersonEmailId }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.SubscriptionStatus }}</td></tr>
```

component.ts file;

```
  ngOnInit() { 
// making use of web API
this.httpService.get('http://url/StudyExAPI/GetOrganisations?Id=').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.orgData = data as string[];
    // console.log(this.orgData);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of objects inside your array, you can use the virtual scroll viewport provided by package `@angular/cdk` which render only visible elements.